# pass shutdown from APC battery backup to VMware Fusion Guest machine

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization, shutdown

How can I pass the shutdown command to the vmware fusion guest (debian)?

I installed vmware tools and if I manually shutdown my Mac it'll pass the command to shutdown the guest system first. However, if I unplug my APC battery backup, the shutdown command is issued to OSX and is not passed to the guest OS.